# Linux/DD-WRT iptables/route/policy based routing - static route wildcard domain to a different gateway

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, dd-wrt

dd-wrt router command:

```
route add *.googlevideo.com gw (anothergatewayonsubnet)
```

use to work on old ddwrt

is there anyway to redirect `*.googlevideo.com` with `route add`, `ip route`, `iptables` to another gateway besides default?

i been on this for a few years...
some like

```
iptables incoming *.googlevideo.com  foward to anothergatewayonsubnet
```

Thank you in advance..

[image]

[image]

request did not go  to static gateway...